# Assets field inside of a grid inside of a low variable -- Asset not saving

Tags: assets, low-variables, grid

Having an issue with a low variable of the "Grid" persuasion.
I have an assets field inside the grid, and I can upload and add the asset just fine, but when I save the Low Variable, the CP never shows the image inside the field, but only an "Add file" button. I checked the database, and the image name is in the field in the low_variables_grid_field_12 table.

Assets work in normal entry fields.

Running EE v.2.7.2 Low Variables v.2.4.0 and Assets 2.2.1

Anyone have any wisdom on this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing this same thing, so it's not just you!

Comment: Looking like an Assets issue, as LV simply calls the Grid field, which handles all the rest. Can't do anything from a LV perspective.

Comment: Any answers on this? Still seems to be happening.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after mucking around for a bit I found the combination was

this was what I was trying to no avail.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="grid_variable_name" limit="1"}
  {grid_variable_name:grid_assets_field}
    {url}
  {/grid_variable_name:grid_assets_field}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

This worked.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="grid_variable_name" limit="1"}
{grid_variable_name:grid_assets_field:url}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Note the assets field I setup was set to single image only.

Comment: This is awesome. Just another example html from inside grid low variable: `<img src="{lv_home_slider:image}" alt="{lv_home_slider:image:desc}" width="960" height="351">`